# Simulating archers hitting a target monte carlo method

Tags: java, probability, montecarlo

3 archers are shooting at a target with probabilities p1, p2, p3. With a Monte Carlo simulation I am supposed to find an approximation of the probabilities of the following events:

- randomly chosen archer hits the target // already solved
- the target will be hit if all three shoot at it with a single bullet. // no idea how to approach

This is the first problem of this type that I am approaching. I can solve it easily using probabilities formulas, but I have no idea how to approach the problem using a simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
public class Archer {
    private Random random = new Random();
    public final double chance;
    public Archer(double chance) {
        this.chance = chance;
    }
    public boolean shoot() {
        return random.nextDouble() < chance;
    }
}

// ...

public boolean sample_problem2() {
    for (Archer archer : archers) {
        if (archer.shoot()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public double estimate_sample2(long count) {
    long positive = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (sample_problem2()) positive++;
    }
    return (double)positive / (double)count;
}
```

Here, the `archer` objects `shoot` method will return true or false with their respective probabilities. `sample_problem2` will simulate an event you need. The latter method will take `count` samples, and will estimate the probability of the simulated event.

If you have some example code, we can help you develop a solution which fits better to what you already have.

Comment: I think I've misunderstood the task. I thought I have only a single sample for the second problem which is why I was so confused :)